# GWT integration with PhoneGap

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, cordova, mgwt

**Edit** - I know there are *similar* questions to this on SO, but I feel my specific questions are not duplicates at all.  If you disagree with me please bring them to my attention before downnvoting or closevoting! If you can prove to me that my question is a true duplicate I will delete this question myself!

My understanding of the GWT is that it provides an SDK and API that allows you to code in Java, and it generates all the client-side HTML, CSS and JavaScript required to run a full-fledged web (or mobile web) app.

My understanding of PhoneGap is that it allows you to code against its JavaScript API and, through configuration, allows you to tell it which native mobile platforms (Android, iOS, Windows Phone, etc.) it should create nativee wrappers for. Hence you "write once, run many" with it, turning your JavaScript code into a native Android app, native iOS app, etc.

If these two assumption are incorrect, please begin by correcting me! And, if there are any caveats to these assumptions, please let me know!

Assuming my understanding on GWT and PhoneGap are more or less correct, I want to try and use them together for an app that would be available as (1) a web app, (2) a mobile web app, (3) an Android app and (4) as an iOS app.

I want to "daisy-chain" these two in my Ant build, whereby my pure Java code is converted (via GWT) into JavaScript (that complies to the PhoneGap API), and then a second build process uses PhoneGap to create and deploy:

- A Java WAR (web and mobile web app)
- An Android APK
- An iOS binary (I *believe* this is an IPA file, but I may be wrong)

So with those as the "givens", here are my questions:

- Is this possible? If not, why? Any way to hack- or juryrig-together a solution that *forces* this to work?
- I've noticed something called `gwt-phonegap` - will I **need** this in order for my proposed solution to work, or would this library just be a "nice to have"? Why or why not?
- Any other considerations I am not thinking of here? Other libraries or tools that would behoove me?

**Note:** I have *heard* (but am not asserting!) that Titanium is superior to PhoneGap. Titanium, however, is not free. And I am quite broke. Thanks in advance for any help here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an open source project out there combining GWT & Phonegap to build mobile apps:

mgwt - http://www.m-gwt.com

There are many people out there using it to build mobile apps and there is quite a lot on documentation including videos there, especially this one:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0V0CdhMFiao&feature=plcp